# Making a Global Countdown in Angular 2 for different viewers to see same time?

Tags: angular

I am having a bit of trouble with this one. I am trying to make an application that includes a countdown viewable from different browsers, from people all over the world. I have succeeded in creating a timer module that displays exactly how I want it. The only problem is, the timer restarts on each page refresh, or any different browser. I would like the timer to start when I start the timer from the server end, not the client end. What is the method I should use? Is this called server-side rendering, or is that something else? I am very new to Angular 2 so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to read the counter from the server and display its value, instead of starting a counter in the client

Comment: Or use a signalR hub...